# HTML/CSS - Scroll bar appears for simple image within div with 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have this simple bit of HTML below, it has a div, which is absoutely position 0,0 to 100%, 100%.   Within the div is an image with width 100%, height, 100%.   I used the google image for this example, but it can be any image.

It creates a vertical scrollbar (in Chrome anyway).

Does anyone know how to avoid that.   I know I can add "overflow: hidden", but if there is other content on the page that goes beyond the 100% screen height, I want it to scroll.  So I don't want to do that.

I can also make it height: 99%, but that's not exactly elegant.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <div id="divBackDrop" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height:100%; width: 100%; border: 0px solid red;"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" /></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just seems like it should work the way it is - I mean there is no horizontal scrollbar, and the width is set up exactly the same way.

Comment: I understand your point and it's a fair one

Comment: are you trying to do a background-image

Comment: Yes, but I want it to stretch to the size of screen ,regardless of aspect, etc.

Comment: Hello look at my answer and change styling to suit your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have done is correct! However browsers like chrome add a scrollbar when the image is large enough to go onto the scrolling region. Instead you should try this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="">
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;height:100%;width:100%;position:fixed;">
   <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. you should note that the position is Position:fixed;.

Comment: @Henrix I don't think this is a good solution because if your content overflows the `<body>` tag, you will never have a scrollbar. Adding `position:fixed;` to body isn't only a very bad practice, it doesn't solve the OP's problem and only provides a patch to his issue. -1

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are facing is that `<img>` is an inline element and therefore adds a white-space.

To prevent that you can add `display:block;` to the image.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/22Jy4/5/)**

BTW, Inline CSS styles are not recomended.